# Prometheus pod unable to call apiserver endpoints

Tags: networking, kubernetes, prometheus

I am trying to set up monitoring stack (prometheus + alertmanager + node_exporter etc) via `helm install stable/prometheus` onto a raspberry pi k8s cluster (1 master + 3 worker nodes) which i set up.

Managed to get all the required pods running.

```
pi-monitoring-prometheus-alertmanager-767cd8bc65-89hxt   2/2     Running            0          131m    10.17.2.56      kube2   <none>           <none>
pi-monitoring-prometheus-node-exporter-h86gt             1/1     Running            0          131m    192.168.1.212   kube2   <none>           <none>
pi-monitoring-prometheus-node-exporter-kg957             1/1     Running            0          131m    192.168.1.211   kube1   <none>           <none>
pi-monitoring-prometheus-node-exporter-x9wgb             1/1     Running            0          131m    192.168.1.213   kube3   <none>           <none>
pi-monitoring-prometheus-pushgateway-799d4ff9d6-rdpkf    1/1     Running            0          131m    10.17.3.36      kube1   <none>           <none>
pi-monitoring-prometheus-server-5d989754b6-gp69j         2/2     Running            0          98m     10.17.1.60      kube3   <none>           <none>
```

however after port-forwarding prometheus server port 9090 and navigating to `Targets` page, i realized none of the node_exporters are registered.

Digging through the logs, i found this

```
evel=error ts=2020-04-12T05:15:05.083Z caller=klog.go:94 component=k8s_client_runtime func=ErrorDepth msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:333: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://10.18.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.18.0.1:443: i/o timeout"
level=error ts=2020-04-12T05:15:05.084Z caller=klog.go:94 component=k8s_client_runtime func=ErrorDepth msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:299: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.18.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.18.0.1:443: i/o timeout"
level=error ts=2020-04-12T05:15:05.084Z caller=klog.go:94 component=k8s_client_runtime func=ErrorDepth msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:261: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.18.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.18.0.1:443: i/o timeout"
level=error ts=2020-04-12T05:15:05.085Z caller=klog.go:94 component=k8s_client_runtime func=ErrorDepth msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:262: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.18.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.18.0.1:443: i/o timeout"
```

**Question: why is the prometheus pod unable to call the apiserver endpoints?  Not really sure where was the configuration done wrongly**

Followed through [debug guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/) and realized individual nodes are unable to resolve services on other nodes.

Been troubleshooting for the past 1 day reading various sources but to be honest, i am not even sure where to begin with.

These are the pods running in `kube-system` namespace. Hope this will give a better idea of how my system is set up.

```
pi@kube4:~ $ kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP              NODE    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
coredns-66bff467f8-nzvq8        1/1     Running   0          13d   10.17.0.2       kube4   <none>           <none>
coredns-66bff467f8-z7wdb        1/1     Running   0          13d   10.17.0.3       kube4   <none>           <none>
etcd-kube4                      1/1     Running   0          13d   192.168.1.214   kube4   <none>           <none>
kube-apiserver-kube4            1/1     Running   2          13d   192.168.1.214   kube4   <none>           <none>
kube-controller-manager-kube4   1/1     Running   2          13d   192.168.1.214   kube4   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-arm-8g9fb       1/1     Running   1          13d   192.168.1.212   kube2   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-arm-c5qt9       1/1     Running   0          13d   192.168.1.214   kube4   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-arm-q5pln       1/1     Running   1          13d   192.168.1.211   kube1   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-arm-tkmn6       1/1     Running   1          13d   192.168.1.213   kube3   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-4zjjh                1/1     Running   0          13d   192.168.1.213   kube3   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-6mk2z                1/1     Running   0          13d   192.168.1.211   kube1   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-bbr8v                1/1     Running   0          13d   192.168.1.212   kube2   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-wfsbm                1/1     Running   0          13d   192.168.1.214   kube4   <none>           <none>
kube-scheduler-kube4            1/1     Running   3          13d   192.168.1.214   kube4   <none>           <none>
```

Comment: maybe firewall blocking connection to master node from worker nodes

Comment: A possible troubleshooting way is to schedule the Prometheus Pod onto the master to assure that both the Prometheus Pod and the API server Pod are on the same node. If the network failure recovered, it is probably the CNI plugin doesn't set SNAT rules for outgoing traffic. Otherwise, it is more like a CNI plugin failure. You can try to reinstall the CNI plugin.

Comment: What hostnames does your nodes have?

Comment: @Crou kube1,kube2,kube3,kube4(master)

Comment: @kitt thank you for your suggestion, why didnt i thought of that. removed NoSchedule taint on master node and deployed prometheus on it and it managed to discover the different node_exporters! however, prometheus is unable to pull metrics from any of the exporters. seems like you are right about the CNI plugin. now to figure out what exactly is CNI plugin...

Comment: @JianHaoTan Which CNI plugin do you have? And, does the prometheus-apiserver connection work after rescheduled?

Comment: @kitt tbh, im not even sure which CNI plugin i have. havent had the time to read up on it. as for the prometheus-apiserver connection, yea its working since it managed to call apiserver to discover the nodes

Comment: Oh, I see it. It's Flannel. Could you please paste the result of `kubectl -n kube-system describe po kube-flannel-ds-arm-c5qt9` and logs of this Pod? @JianHaoTan

Comment: not sure how can i share the `describe` result here, but i found this in logs `github.com/coreos/flannel/subnet/kube/kube.go:307: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://10.18.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes?resourceVersion=0: net/http: TLS handshake timeout`, in which `10.18.0.1` belongs to kubernetes service

Comment: flannel was set up via `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml`

Comment: i also saw this `github.com/coreos/flannel/subnet/kube/kube.go:307: watch of *v1.Node ended with: very short watch`

Comment: @JianHaoTan Did you change anything in the flannel manifest before installing, especially the network CIDR in kube-flannel.yml? The default CIDR in the yml file is `10.244.0.0/16`, which is not the same as yours, seems your CIDR is 10.17/16.

Comment: `sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.17.0.0/16 --service-cidr=10.18.0.0/24 --service-dns-domain=jaan.io` ah that explains! so i have to configure CIDR in flannel yml to follow the pod-network cidr.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211725/discussion-between-kitt-and-jian-hao-tan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flannel documentation](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kubernetes.md) states:

> NOTE: If `kubeadm` is used, then pass `--pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` to `kubeadm init` to ensure that the `podCIDR` is set.

This is because flannel ConfigMap by default is configured to work on `"Network": "10.244.0.0/16"`

You have configured your kubeadm with `--pod-network-cidr=10.17.0.0/16` now this needs to be configured in flannel ConfigMap `kube-flannel-cfg` to look like this:

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kube-flannel-cfg
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    tier: node
    app: flannel
data:
  cni-conf.json: |
    {
      "name": "cbr0",
      "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
      "plugins": [
        {
          "type": "flannel",
          "delegate": {
            "hairpinMode": true,
            "isDefaultGateway": true
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "portmap",
          "capabilities": {
            "portMappings": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  net-conf.json: |
    {
      "Network": "10.17.0.0/16",
      "Backend": {
        "Type": "vxlan"
      }
    }
```

Thanks to [@kitt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5689112/kitt) for his debugging help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a networking issue that prevents you from reaching the API server.  "dial tcp 10.18.0.1:443: i/o timeout" generally reflects that you are not able to connect or read from the server. You can use below steps to figure out the problem:
 1. Deploy one busybox pod using `kubectl run busybox --image=busybox -n kube-system`
 2. Get into the pod using `kubectl exec -n kube-system -it <podname> sh` 
 3. Try to do telnet from the tty like `telnet 10.18.0.1 443` to figure out the connection issues

Let me know the output.

Comment: for some reason, it kept crashing and running`kubectl logs -n kube-system busybox` did not show anything

Comment: got it to work by running `kubectl run busy --image busybox --namespace kube-system -it --generator=run-pod/v1` . running `telnet 10.18.0.1 443` returns `telnet: can't connect to remote host (10.18.0.1): Connection timed out``

Answer (score 0):

After much troubleshooting, i realized i am not able to ping other pods from other nodes but only able to ping from those within the node. Issue seems to be with iptables config as covered here https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/699.

tl;dr: running `iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT` solved my problem. 
prior to updating iptables policy

```
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding rules */
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

issue it solved now. thanks @kitt for the help earlier!