# How to Up kubernetes-apiservers terget in Istio enabled prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio

I installed istio 1.5.6 with grafana and prometheous plugin/addons.All are workings fine except prometheus pods is throwing the below error.Prometheus is unable to connect with kube-api server which is shown down over terget in prometheus dashboard.Can any please help me to solve this issue ?

```
kubectl logs -f prometheus_xxxxx -n istio-system

level=error ts=2020-07-07T04:10:12.779Z caller=klog.go:94 component=k8s_client_runtime func=ErrorDepth msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:263: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://x.x.x.1:443/api/v1/pods?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp x.x.x.1:443: i/o timeout"
```

Comment: Hi, what k8s version do You use?

Comment: This looks like an RBAC error. Check if You have `ClusterRole` and `ClusterRoleBinding`  objects configured for Your prometheus to access kube-api.

Comment: k8s  version is 1.16.9 and i will look into the cluster role

Comment: Have You managed to fix the issue?

Comment: @PiotrMalec not yet

Comment: Hi @Taybur Rahaman do you still need help with that? Could you tell me what is your infrastructure(cloud or on-prem)? Have you tried with newest istio version or you need this specific one? There is [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19532) about that on gke.

Comment: @Jakub, yes still i need help to solve this one.
i have a cluster running in aws created using kops. Installed istio version 1.5.6 with prometheous and grafana addon.

Comment: Have you prepared kops before installing Istio as mentioned [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/platform-setup/kops/)? From the error it seems like Prometheus pod is unable to call apiserver endpoints, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168194/prometheus-pod-unable-to-call-apiserver-endpoints), might be related.

Comment: hi @Jakub, i think, the second link is good to try, i will let you know the result.